# Is there a way to fix this code or should I ask to change the data structure?

Tags: loops, rust, data-structures, logic, recursive-datastructures

I'm loosing my mind with this (because I'm not a very logic person).

[RUST Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eab750fd79efbc36394e4b87b363ab8a)

**I cannot change the data part.**

The string returned from the below code is `A = 1 AND (B = 2 OR C = 3 OR D = 4 OR )` instead of what I need (`A = 1 AND (B = 2 OR C = 3 OR D = 4)`).

**What I don't understand is how to avoid the last "OR".**

How can I fix the below code?

```rust
enum Token {
    Str(&'static str),
    Value(&'static str),
    StartGroup(&'static str),
    EndGroup,
}

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<Vec<Token>> = vec![
        vec![Token::Str("A = "), Token::Value("1")],
        vec![Token::Str(" AND ("), Token::StartGroup(" OR ")],
        vec![Token::Str("B = "), Token::Value("2")],
        vec![Token::Str("C = "), Token::Value("3")],
        vec![Token::Str("D = "), Token::Value("4")],
        vec![Token::EndGroup, Token::Str(")")],
    ];

    let result = construct_string(data);

    assert_eq!("A = 1 AND (B = 2 OR C = 3 OR D = 4)", result);
}

fn construct_string(tokens: Vec<Vec<Token>>) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();

    let mut current = String::new();
    let mut next = String::new();

    for token in tokens {
        for part in token {
            match part {
                Token::Str(str) => {
                    result.push_str(str);
                }
                Token::Value(val) => {
                    result.push_str(val);
                }
                Token::StartGroup(group) => {
                    next = group.to_string();
                }
                Token::EndGroup => {
                    current = String::new();
                    next = String::new();
                }
            }
        }

        if !current.is_empty() {
            result.push_str(&current);
        }

        current = next.to_string();
    }

    result
}
```

Comment: It will help if instead of having to decipher it ourselves, you will explain how the code is structured and what the enum variants represent.

Comment: Hi Chayim, can I ask you which part is difficult to understand?

Comment: The enum variants, their role and what is the data they contain.

Comment: The issue are not the enum now. What I don't understand is how to avoid the last "OR". The enum are to differs the various parts of the token.

Comment: If you're _inside_ a group, then only add `next`, if the _next_ token is not `EndGroup`?

Comment: Yes, but to understand the code and how it's wrong, we need to understand them.

Comment: The how is a bit hard to ask, because we have to make assumptions. When does the `group`(`OR`) need to be added? Only after `Token::Value`? What about consecutive `Token::Str`? If only after values, then add `group` if the previous token as a value and the current token is not `EndGroup`

Comment: Yeah. The thing is I cannot change the data part. Is not under my control.

Comment: Of course. It's not about changing the data, it's about understanding the rules of the data. If it's always `Str Val OR Str Val OR Str Val`, then that's simple enough. But what about `Str Str Val Val Val Str`, is that valid data? and if yes, where are the `OR` then? That's why we're confused. If it's only the first case that is valid, then what I said previously will work :)

Comment: It can be everything. Not just `Str Val`.

Comment: In that case, we'd need more context, or more `assert`s to compare to. Again, for just the case you've posted, what I described fulfills that. Here's a [snippet on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bea4590f7ca8aa4a6ca53e497bb4ce42). But we're lacking context, to know if that's THE solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved `EndGroup` to the previous vector and it worked:

```
enum Token {
    Str(&'static str),
    Value(&'static str),
    StartGroup(&'static str),
    EndGroup,
}

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<Vec<Token>> = vec![
        vec![Token::Str("A = "), Token::Value("1")],
        vec![Token::Str(" AND ("), Token::StartGroup(" OR ")],
        vec![Token::Str("B = "), Token::Value("2")],
        vec![Token::Str("C = "), Token::Value("3")],
        vec![Token::Str("D = "), Token::Value("4"), Token::EndGroup],
        vec![ Token::Str(")")],
    ];

    let result = construct_string(data);

    assert_eq!("A = 1 AND (B = 2 OR C = 3 OR D = 4)", result);
}

fn construct_string(tokens: Vec<Vec<Token>>) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();

    let mut current = String::new();
    let mut next = String::new();

    for token in tokens {
        for part in token {
            match part {
                Token::Str(str) => {
                    result.push_str(str);
                }
                Token::Value(val) => {
                    result.push_str(val);
                }
                Token::StartGroup(group) => {
                    next = group.to_string();
                }
                Token::EndGroup => {
                    current = String::new();
                    next = String::new();
                }
            }
        }

        if !current.is_empty() {
            result.push_str(&current);
        }

        current = next.to_string();
    }

    result
}
```

EDIT

Applied a fix inside `construct_string`, please take a look (the idea is to differentiate whether the delimiter has to appear):

```
enum Token {
    Str(&'static str),
    Value(&'static str),
    StartGroup(&'static str),
    EndGroup,
}

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<Vec<Token>> = vec![
        vec![Token::Str("A = "), Token::Value("1")],
        vec![Token::Str(" AND ("), Token::StartGroup(" OR ")],
        vec![Token::Str("B = "), Token::Value("2")],
        vec![Token::Str("C = "), Token::Value("3")],
        vec![Token::Str("D = "), Token::Value("4")],
        vec![Token::EndGroup, Token::Str(")")],
    ];

    let result = construct_string(data);

    assert_eq!("A = 1 AND (B = 2 OR C = 3 OR D = 4)", result);
}

fn construct_string(tokens: Vec<Vec<Token>>) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();

    //let mut current = String::new();
    let mut next = String::new();
    
    let mut new_group = true;

    for token in tokens {
        for part in token {
            match part {
                Token::Str(str) => {
                    if !new_group {
                        result.push_str(&next);
                    }
                    new_group = false;
                    result.push_str(str);
                }
                Token::Value(val) => {
                    result.push_str(val);
                }
                Token::StartGroup(group) => {
                    new_group = true;
                    next = group.to_string();
                }
                Token::EndGroup => {
                    //current = String::new();
                    next = String::new();
                }
            }
        }

        //if !current.is_empty() {
          //  result.push_str(&current);
        //}

        //current = next.to_string();
    }

    result
}
```

Comment: Oh. Wow. This is like "cheating". I cannot change the "data" part.

Comment: @FredHors is this fix working for you? Why can't you modify the data part? In the initial question this was not specified.

Comment: Yeah, I know that this can be a solution. But the data part is not under my control.

Comment: @FredHors applied another fix, pleae take a look. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Your code is absolutely brilliant! Thanks! Anyway I slightly modified it to prove an issue with nested groups, do you want another question on SO for this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d0752aa926e99fa464c30bfd7656b46f

Comment: @FredHors the issue is that I'm not fluent with Rust, this is the first time I'm coding in this language. Your second problem will be solvable by using a stack for the delimiters and always .push() the delimiters whenever a group starts and .pop() whenever a group ends. Consequently, you will need a new_group flag for each level of the stack, so the different levels will properly be handled. I'm afraid this surpasses my Rust knowledge, but if we open a separate question and link this one to it, then the Rust gurus will see this solution, the ideas we had and they will be able to

Comment: @FredHors add a stack to it. I might also give it a try, but I'm not fluent in Rust. If we mark this answer as a solution for the one-level problem, then we both help future readers and will also help the Rust gurus to start their thought process from this milestone.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77922269/what-data-structure-do-i-need-to-handle-this-data.

Comment: @FredHors I will try to figure this out, but my lack of Rust knowledge will make me slow. It's good we have separated the one-leveled question from the one with nested groups.