# What data structure do I need to handle this data?

Tags: loops, rust, data-structures, logic

After the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77921119/is-there-a-way-to-fix-this-code-or-should-i-ask-to-change-the-data-structure) I'm now facing the issue of nested groups. Hence this question.

In the below code ([here the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=75f7a494170d47d4741933879a1fbb20)) some `assert` does not work.

I'm tyring to understand what data structure to use. Can you help me?

```rust
enum Token {
    Str(&'static str),
    Value(&'static str),
    StartGroup(&'static str),
    EndGroup,
}

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<Vec<Token>> = vec![
        vec![Token::Str("A = "), Token::Value("1")],
        vec![Token::StartGroup(" OR ")],
        vec![Token::Str("B = "), Token::Value("2")],
        vec![Token::Str("C = "), Token::Value("3")],
        vec![Token::Str("D = "), Token::Value("4")],
        vec![Token::EndGroup],
    ];

    assert_eq!(
        "A = 1 AND (B = 2 OR C = 3 OR D = 4)",
        construct_string(data)
    );

    let nested_data: Vec<Vec<Token>> = vec![
        vec![Token::Str("A = "), Token::Value("1")],
        vec![Token::StartGroup(" OR ")],
        vec![Token::Str("E = "), Token::Value("5")],
        vec![Token::Str("F = "), Token::Value("6")],
        vec![Token::Str("G = "), Token::Value("7")],
        vec![Token::EndGroup],
        vec![Token::StartGroup(" AND ")],
        vec![Token::Str("M = "), Token::Value("8")],
        vec![Token::Str("N = "), Token::Value("9")],
        vec![Token::Str("O = "), Token::Value("10")],
        vec![Token::StartGroup(" OR ")],
        vec![Token::Str("B = "), Token::Value("2")],
        vec![Token::Str("C = "), Token::Value("3")],
        vec![Token::EndGroup],
        vec![Token::EndGroup],
    ];

    assert_eq!(
        "A = 1 AND (E = 5 OR F = 6 OR G = 7) AND (M = 8 AND N = 9 AND O = 10 AND (B = 2 OR C = 3))",
        construct_string(nested_data)
    );

    let different_nested_data: Vec<Vec<Token>> = vec![
        vec![Token::Str("A = "), Token::Value("1")],
        vec![Token::StartGroup(" OR ")],
        vec![Token::StartGroup(" OR ")],
        vec![Token::Str("B = "), Token::Value("2")],
        vec![Token::Str("C = "), Token::Value("3")],
        vec![Token::EndGroup],
        vec![Token::Str("E = "), Token::Value("5")],
        vec![Token::Str("F = "), Token::Value("6")],
        vec![Token::Str("G = "), Token::Value("7")],
        vec![Token::EndGroup],
    ];

    assert_eq!(
        "A = 1 AND ((B = 2 OR C = 3) OR E = 5 OR F = 6 OR G = 7)",
        construct_string(different_nested_data)
    );

    let more_difficult_data: Vec<Vec<Token>> = vec![
        vec![Token::Str("A = "), Token::Value("1")],
        vec![Token::StartGroup(" OR ")],
        vec![Token::Str("B = "), Token::Value("2")],
        vec![
            Token::Str("C = ANY("),
            Token::Value("[3,4]"),
            Token::Str(")"),
        ],
        vec![Token::EndGroup],
    ];

    assert_eq!(
        "A = 1 AND (B = 2 OR C = ANY([1,2]))",
        construct_string(more_difficult_data)
    );

    let simple_data: Vec<Vec<Token>> = vec![
        vec![Token::StartGroup(" AND ")],
        vec![Token::Str("A = "), Token::Value("1")],
        vec![Token::Str("B = "), Token::Value("2")],
        vec![Token::EndGroup],
    ];

    assert_eq!("A = 1 AND B = 2", construct_string(simple_data));
}

fn construct_string(tokens: Vec<Vec<Token>>) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();

    let mut new_group = true;
    let mut stack: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    for token in tokens {
        if !new_group && stack.is_empty() {
            result.push_str(" AND ");
        }

        for part in token {
            match part {
                Token::Str(str) => {
                    if let Some(group) = stack.last() {
                        if !new_group {
                            result.push_str(group);
                        }
                    }
                    new_group = false;
                    result.push_str(str);
                }
                Token::Value(val) => {
                    result.push_str(val);
                }
                Token::StartGroup(group) => {
                    result.push_str("(");
                    new_group = true;
                    stack.push(group.to_string());
                }
                Token::EndGroup => {
                    result.push_str(")");
                    stack.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    result
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you keep all the current "groups" around, so when you end a nested group there is suddenly *no* "group" so there's no separator to add even when a parent group hasn't ended yet. You need to keep a stack of group separators, apply the top one if there is one, and pop it off when the group ends.

Comment: Oh wow. But a big HOW in my head now! :) LOL

Comment: This is how far I reached with my nonexistent Rust knowledge: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1cd21adb61745e860aca9cc499ea56e . The technical issue I stumbled into is that for some reason Option<String> is not converted to the proper type when I intend to push the result to the stack.

Comment: @LajosArpad thank you. Forget about the String issue for now. I updated the question, can you please hlep me using static strings for now?

Comment: What I need is logic.

Comment: Why is your `data` structure so horrible? It seems like it knows what goes in a group, but then why is it represented so flat instead of a nested structure that it should be? Why do "tokens" span multiple syntactic elements? Why are you constructing a string when it looks like this data came from a string in the first place? This is bizarre to look at.

Comment: @kmdreko, this data comes from javascript frontend. It is firstly serialized in a Rust struct and then another function collects field by field all the one needed creating the `Vec<Vec<Token>>`. How can I improve it? (this is the question about too, thanks in advance).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed all of them except the last assert:

```
assertion `left == right` failed
    left: "A = 1 AND B = 2"
    right: "(A = 1 AND B = 2)"
```

but I still think there is much space for improvement.

For example I have this repetition which I don't know how to remove:

```rust
if let Some(group) = stack.last() {
    if !new_group && i == 0 {
        result.push_str(group);
    }
}
```

[The playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2b53b47859c5599469a9bd9e71e9fd6)

The code:

```rust
fn construct_string(tokens: Vec<Vec<Token>>) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();

    let mut stack: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let mut new_group = true;

    for token in tokens {
        if !new_group && stack.is_empty() {
            result.push_str(" AND ");
        }

        for (i, part) in token.iter().enumerate() {
            match part {
                Token::Str(str) => {
                    if let Some(group) = stack.last() {
                        if !new_group && i == 0 {
                            result.push_str(group);
                        }
                    }
                    new_group = false;
                    result.push_str(str);
                }
                Token::Value(val) => {
                    result.push_str(val);
                }
                Token::StartGroup(group) => {
                    if let Some(group) = stack.last() {
                        if !new_group && i == 0 {
                            result.push_str(group);
                        }
                    }
                    result.push_str("(");
                    new_group = true;
                    stack.push(group.to_string());
                }
                Token::EndGroup => {
                    result.push_str(")");
                    stack.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    result
}
```

Comment: Answers should be self-contained. Please include the code in the answer itself.